# How to sort stopped EC2s by time using "state_transition_reason" variable? Python Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I am seeing a steep increase on my AWS account costs. The largest cost items are: **EC2: 67% RDS: 12%**

I have more than 50 stopped EC2s. One of them has been sitting there in a stopped state from September of the year 2015.

I found the way to get the stopped time of EC2s using variable called:

> state_transition_reason

Here how the code looks:

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(region_name="us-east-1")
ec2 = session.resource('ec2')

instances = ec2.instances.filter(
            Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['stopped']}])

count = 0

for i in instances:
   print "{0}, {1}, {2}".format( i.id, i.state_transition_reason, i.state['Name']) 
   count +=1

print count
```

It prints out the following information:

```
i-pll78233b, User initiated (2016-07-06 21:14:03 GMT), stopped
i-tr62l5647, User initiated (2015-12-18 21:35:20 GMT), stopped
i-9oc4391ca, User initiated (2016-03-17 04:37:46 GMT), stopped
55
```

**My question is**: How can I sort instances (EC2s) by their time being stopped. In my example I would love to see the output in the following order starting from year 2015 accordingly:

```
i-tr62l5647, User initiated (2015-12-18 21:35:20 GMT), stopped
i-9oc4391ca, User initiated (2016-03-17 04:37:46 GMT), stopped
i-pll78233b, User initiated (2016-07-06 21:14:03 GMT), stopped
55
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the User initiated part never varies, we can simply sort the instances by state_transition_reason:

```
sortedInstances = sorted(instances, key=lambda k: k.state_transition_reason)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a million.

Comment: How would I sort them in a certain time frame. For example, Instances that were stopped 3 months ago, 6 months ago etc. That way I would put them on AWS Lambda to automate the Termination of Stopped EC2s, that have been stopped for a certain amount of time. Thank you again, you are Great!

Comment: All your dreams will come true at this link :) http://blog.ranman.org/cleaning-up-aws-with-boto3/

Comment: I've been staring at this blog for the last 3 days. Let me review their solution again. Thanks, Danielle M.